# Does a WebView in two different processes of a single app share web caches?

Tags: android, webview, process

In short, two WebView instances in two different process of one single app, do the two WebView instances share web caches?

Comment: were you able to resolve the problem?

Comment: @AnushaMathur yes, after search from google and read some pages, WebView cache does need set directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'll need to set a different data directory using `setDataDirectorySuffix`.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setDataDirectorySuffix(java.lang.String)

Comment: Can you please share your complete solution along with code snippet? I tried this, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            String processName = getProcessName();
            String packageName = getPackageName();
            if (!packageName.equals(processName)) {
                WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(processName);
            }
        }
```